# Force Thunderbird to open new child windows on screen center

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird

I have a mulitmonitor setting and Thunderbird opens it's child windows outer view since the last update. One monitor is also connected to a KVM switch. After switching through the clients, one computer always struggels with the display settings. So all recently opened program windows are on one monitor. This just as a hint. Anyway, I search for a config file of thunderbird which sets the rule, where new windows are shown. For now, I always have to move them into the visible field  of view. It happens to any thunderbirds child windows like "new mail", "appointment recognitions", etc.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome aboard. If Thunderbird can't do it, you might be able to find an app to do so. Visit us at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/